# Best Way to Get All DOM Elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the best way to get all of the DOM elements on a page using jQuery?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Edit: This is for use in a script that grayscales an entire page using grayscale.js - http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/. jQuery because I can! :P

Comment: I think it depends of what are you going to do with those elements. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I think I saw this movie once, it didn't end well

Comment: I would be surprised if this is the best way to accomplish your task, whatever that may be.

Comment: Maybe there's a prize in one of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var allOfThem = $('*');
```

You don't really need jQuery for this:

```
var allOfThem = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Comment: No - to get all text nodes via jQuery, I think you'd have to work at it. You'd have to work down the tree finding them either through DOM APIs or with jQuery `.contents()`.

Comment: @jAndy: It's worth noting, however, that it *does* return comment nodes on IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("*")` will return all DOM elements as "actual" elements, with all their contents and properties and everything.

`$('*')` or `$("body *")` will return array of "jQuery objects", each only pointing on true element. To get the true element, you'll have to use the specific jQuery object.

Guess this difference is what causing this behavior of browser crashing when getting all elements vs. getting all jQuery objects.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("*") will return all DOM elements as "actual" elements, // lie. Sometimes it is seemingly impossible to enumerate all actual elements at certain step. Refer to my DOM/Gmail questions, and look for long code to enumerate all elements from all frames.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want `$("body *")`, which is equivalent to `document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('*')`

Weirdly, `getElementsByTagName('*')` seems to crash my Firefox/Firebug, while jQuery version works fine