# jQuery : Perform same action for each element on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read so many related questions, the list is given below but none seems to be applicable in my situation.

I want that a border should appear around the element. I have tried the below code but $("*") selects all the elements in the hierarchy, and the border appears around parent elements as well, which is not what I want. I want to select only the clicked element, and NOT THE PARENT ELEMENTS.

**Here is the script**

```
$( "*" ).each(function(){ 
    $(this).on( "mousedown", function(){
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
    }); 

$(this).on( "mouseup", function(){
        $(this).css("border-style", "none");
    });
});
```

Here goes a list of some of my 'not so useful' research: - 
[javascript - Best Way to Get All DOM Elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024027/best-way-to-get-all-dom-elements-with-jquery)

[jquery get all form elements: input, textarea & select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select)

[All Selector (“*”) | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: any html.  for example : try the above script in the console of this page: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `*` selector is incredibly inefficient as it adds an event handler to *every* element in the DOM. You could use event propagation to do this instead by placing the event handler on the `document` and referencing the element which triggered the event using the `target` property. Try this:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css('border', '1px solid red');
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css('border', '0');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fs6a520u/)

Comment: @RameshPareek you may kindly consider accepting the answer if you think this answer helped you today. :)

Comment: would you suggest   $(e.target).css('border', '0'); and not   $(this).css("border-style", "none"); ?

Comment: yes but SO says that you must wait for 3 more minutes to accept the answer. in fact i've tried 3 times to accept it . :)

Comment: @RameshPareek You would have to use `e.target` as `this` would refer to the `document`